# Form will not reach post action without /Index in MVC4

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've recently upgrade a project to MVC 4. I've got a Login page at Account/Index. When using Html.BeginForm the post action in the controller was not being reached.

After some further messing around I discovered that the HTML being produced by the helper was:

```
<form action="/Account" autocomplete="off" method="post" requireSSL="true">
```

If I replace the Html.BeginForm with html like so:

```
<form action="/Account/Index" autocomplete="off" method="post" requireSSL="true">
```

The post action is correctly reached.

I can't understand why? This always worked previously for MVC 3. The routes registered are the standard Microsoft template:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RedirectUser");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl != "/")
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("RedirectUser", "Account");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your routing looks ok, the problem is probably an incorrectly used the [HttpPost] attribute. If you specify what Action does the post trigger, I might be able to help more.

Is there a difference when navigating to /Account/Index vs /Account/ with a browser? If not, it's definately an incorrectly used attribute.

Comment: Yes it works fine for gets (when navigating in browser or via fiddler). Posts in fiddler work when pointed to /Account/Index but not when pointed to /Account.

Comment: So when you debug, it fires up the first instance of Index instead of the second one? (decorated with the HttpPost attribute). If so, try setting default values on `Index(LogOnModel model = null, string returnUrl = "")`. Zipping up and uploading the project (or host on a public git and the like) is better for direct help with this

Answer (score 0):

It Does seem to be an issue, even if you enter it in browser. Bug needs to be reported